# Creating Role that type of key be integer in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've changed string key to int key in ASP.NET Identity in my project.
When we want to create a role by string key, we can write

```
public class AppRole : IdentityRole {

    public AppRole() : base() { }

    public AppRole(string name) : base(name) { }
}
//IdentityRole class is for ASP.NET Identity
public class IdentityRole : IdentityRole<string, IdentityUserRole>
{
    public IdentityRole();
    public IdentityRole(string roleName);
}
```

There is a constructor that takes a parameter as a role name.
But when I want to create a role by int key, there is no constructor for passing a role name.

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>
{
    public Role() : base() { }
}
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
}
//IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole> class is for ASP.NET Identity
public class IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole> : IRole<TKey> where TUserRole : global::Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole<TKey>
{
    public IdentityRole();
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TUserRole> Users { get; }
}
```

I want to use `IdentityResult result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new Role(name));` for creating a role but I have to pass a role name in an instance of Role, new Role(name).
It's not possible.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you simply missing a Role constructor taking a string name parameter, or am I missing something here? I'm assuming that AppRole, IdentityRole and Role are your own classes as I'm not familiar with the ASP.NET identity classes. Maybe that's a faulty assumption?

Comment: In summary, I want to create a role that Role ID is integer. It means I want to use Role class for this purpose.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IdentityResult result = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new Role { Name = roleName });
```